# Из корутины в Main

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Есть метод, который по ссылке возвращает json геокодинг по координатам:

```
private fun urlRead() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val lng = intent.getDoubleExtra(LAT, 0.0)
        val lat = intent.getDoubleExtra(LNG, 0.0)
        val apiKey = "..."
        val geocodeURL = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=$apiKey&format=json&geocode=$lat,$lng"
        val apiResponse = URL(geocodeURL).readText()
        val txtAddressArray = getAddressLines(apiResponse)
        txtAddress.setText(txtAddressArray[0])
        val txtAddressAdapter = ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, txtAddressArray)
        txtAddressAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.autocomplete_layout)
        txtAddress.setAdapter(txtAddressAdapter)
    }
}
```

При попытке метод запустить вылезает ошибка:

`Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Что значит, что нельзя из других потоков взаимодействовать с основым. Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нам известно, что в основном потоке выполняются операции с UI. Сетевые операции выполняем в другом потоке:

```
fun fetchData() : Deferred<String> {
        return GlobalScope.async {
            // код
            URL(geocodeURL).readText()
        }
    }
```

Затем, например, в активности:

```
MainScope().launch {
            val result = fetchData().await()
            val txtAddressArray = getAddressLines(result)
            txtAddress.setText(txtAddressArray[0])
            // и далее обновление UI
        }
```

Можно поступить и другим образом: передать LiveData в Вашу функцию, записать методом post данные в LiveData, в активности написать observer на LiveData и в нем обновлять UI.